# Change timestamp to date

Tags: r, date, timestamp

My data format is "Posted Today 10:12 AM". I want to change it to 2017-05-12 10:12:00

How can I change it using R? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you need to consider timezone ? What are the other possible date format you got ? for example, will there be "Posted Yesterday 10:12 AM" ? What if the date is few days before, what will it show with your date format ?

Comment: Why is 'today' 3 days ago?

Comment: Your code for current date ??

Comment: %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S used this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your question is incomplete but I'm guessing the format

```
#assuming this is how your date looks like
a<-data.frame("5/14/17", "10:12 AM")
#giving name
colnames(a)<-c("date", "time")
#convert to your expected format
as.POSIXlt(paste(a$date, a$time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Why would you assume their data format is `"5/14/17", "10:12 AM"` when they state: '*My data format is "Posted Today 10:12 AM"*'?

Comment: I think he meant "today" as "date", "posted today" means nothing! In case he has it all as "posted today", he just has to replace the wording with today's date which is trivial in my opinion